# Sorting by count number and case-insensitive

Tags: java, hashmap, case-insensitive

I'm having troubles with the code not ignoring case. Here's what I need to do

## problem

`processInput()` should open and parse the input file.  It should throw any potential exceptions and allow the using class to handle them.

`generateStatsFile()` should produce the XML file described below.  It should also throw any potential exceptions and allow the using class to handle them.  You can use PrintWriter to create your XML File, but you should research better options. See the code sample attached to this lab.

## TEXT FILE ANALYZER

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class TextFileAnalyzer {

private File inputFile;
private File statsXMLFile;
private ArrayList<Word> words;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    TextFileAnalyzer oneTime = new TextFileAnalyzer();
    oneTime.processInput(map);
}

public void processInput(HashMap<String, Integer> map) {

    System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName = keyboard.next();

    try {
        keyboard = new Scanner(new File(fileName)).useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]+");

    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {

        System.out.println("The file: '" + fileName + "' does not exist!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // has it print line by line
    while (keyboard.hasNext()) {`enter code here`

        String word = keyboard.next();
        if (map.containsKey(word)) {
            map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(word, 1);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        System.out.println(entry);
    }

    keyboard.close();

}

public void generateStatsFile(HashMap<String, Integer> map) {
         //SOMECODE TO EXPORT TO XML
}

}
```

==============

## WORD

```
import java.io.*;
public class Word implements Comparable {

private String word;
private int usageCnt;

public Word() {
    this("??", 0);
}

public Word(String word, int usageCnt) {

}

public void reset(String word, int usageCnt) {
    this.setWord(word);
    this.usageCnt = usageCnt;
}

// ACCESSORS
public String getWord() {
    return word;
}

public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}

public int getUsageCnt() {
    return usageCnt;
}

public void setUsageCnt(int usageCnt) {
    this.usageCnt = usageCnt;
}

// COMPARABLE
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return usageCnt;

}
```

}

## ORIGINAL TEXT #

```
Green Eggs and Ham
By Dr. Seuss

I am Sam

Sam I am

That Sam-I-am!
That Sam-I-am!
I do not like
that Sam-I-am!

Do you like green eggs and ham?

I do not like them, Sam-I-am.
I do not like green eggs and ham.

Would you like them here or there?

I would not like them here or there.
I would not like them anywhere.
I do not like green eggs and ham.
I do not like them, Sam-I-am.

Would you like them in a house?
Would you like them with a mouse?

I do not like them in a house.
I do not like them with a mouse.
I do not like them here or there.
I do not like them anywhere.
I do not like green eggs and ham.
I do not like them, Sam-I-am.

Would you eat them in a box?
Would you eat them with a fox?

Not in a box.
Not with a fox.
Not in a house.
Not with a mouse.
I would not eat them here or there.
I would not eat them anywhere.
I would not eat green eggs and ham.
I do not like them, Sam-I-am.

Would you?  Could you?
In a car?  
Eat them!  Eat them!
Here they are.

I would not, could not, in a car.

You may like them.
You will see.
You may like them in a tree!

I would not, could not in a tree.
Not in a car!  You let me be.
I do not like them in a box.
I do not like them with a fox.
I do not like them in a house.
I do not like them with a mouse.
I do not like them here or there.
I do not like them anywhere.
I do not like green eggs and ham.
I do not like them, Sam-I-am.

A train!  A train!
A train!  A train!
Could you, would you, on a train?

Not on a train!  Not in a tree!
Not in a car!  Sam!  Let me be!
I would not, could not, in a box.
I could not, would not, with a fox.
I will not eat them with a mouse.
I will not eat them in a house.
I will not eat them here or there.
I will not eat them anywhere.
I do not eat green eggs and ham.
I do not like them, Sam-I-am.

Say!
In the dark?  Here in the dark!
Would you, could you, in the dark?

I would not, could not, in the dark.

Would you, could you, in the rain?

I would not, could not, in the rain.
Not in the dark.  Not on a train.
Not in a car.  Not in a tree.
I do not like them, Sam, you see.
Not in a house.  Not in a box.
Not with a mouse.  Not with a fox.
I will not eat them here or there.
I do not like them anywhere!

You do not like green eggs and ham?

I do not like them, Sam-I-am.

Could you, would you, with a goat?

I would not, could not, with a goat!

Would you, could you, on a boat?

I could not, would not, on a boat.
I will not, will not, with a goat.
I will not eat them in the rain.
I will not eat them on a train.
Not in the dark!  Not in a tree!
Not in a car!  You let me be!
I do not like them in a box.
I do not like them with a fox.
I will not eat them in a house.
I do not like them with a mouse.
I do not like them here or there.
I do not like them ANYWHERE!
I do not like green eggs and ham!
I do not like them, Sam-I-am.

You do not like them.
So you say.
Try them!  Try them!
And you may.
Try them and you may, I say.

Sam!
If you will let me be, I will try them.
You will see.

<at which point in our story, the heretofore tormented hero cautiously 
 takes a bite of the "green eggs and ham">

Say!
I like green eggs and ham!
I do!  I like them, Sam-I-am!
And I would eat them in a boat.
And I would eat them with a goat...
And I will eat them in the rain.
And in the dark.  And on a train.
And in a car.  And in a tree.
They are so good, so good, you see!
So I will eat them in a box.
And I will eat them with a fox.
And I will eat them in a house.
And I will eat them with a mouse.
And I will eat them here and there.
Say!  I will eat them ANYWHERE!

I do so like
green eggs and ham!
Thank you!
Thank you,
Sam-I-am!
```

## CORRECT OUTPUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<TEXT_ANALYZER>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>not</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>84</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>i</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>71</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>them</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>61</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>a</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>60</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>like</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>44</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>in</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>41</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>do</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>37</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>you</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>34</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>and</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>27</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>would</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>26</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>eat</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>25</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>will</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>21</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>with</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>19</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>could</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>14</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>the</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>13</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>sam-i-am</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>13</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>ham</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>13</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>eggs</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>13</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>green</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>12</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>here</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>11</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>train</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>9</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>there</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>9</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>or</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>8</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>mouse</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>8</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>house</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>8</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>anywhere</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>8</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>on</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>7</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>fox</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>7</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>dark</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>7</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>car</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>7</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>box</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>7</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>tree</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>6</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>so</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>5</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>say</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>5</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>sam</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>5</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>try</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>4</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>see</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>4</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>rain</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>4</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>me</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>4</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>may</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>4</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>let</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>4</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>goat</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>4</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>be</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>4</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>that</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>3</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>boat</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>3</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>they</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>2</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>thank</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>2</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>good</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>2</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>are</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>2</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>am</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>2</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>which</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>tormented</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>takes</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>story</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>seuss</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>point</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>our</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>of</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>if</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>hero</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>heretofore</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>dr</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>cautiously</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>by</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>bite</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>&lt;at</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
  <WORD>
    <WORD_TEXT>"green</WORD_TEXT>
    <USAGE_CNT>1</USAGE_CNT>
  </WORD>
</TEXT_ANALYZER>
```

## WHAT IS DISPLAYING

```
Enter file name: green_eggs_and_ham.txt
heretofore=1
do=36
anywhere=6
good=2
Eggs=1
that=1
mouse=8
would=17
ham=12
me=4
let=3
Try=3
Thank=2
you=26
they=1
train=9
cautiously=1
which=1
eggs=12
rain=4
Seuss=1
like=44
in=39
tree=6
them=61
Do=1
goat=4
am=15
Dr=1
Not=19
Here=2
at=1
And=12
Eat=2
try=1
If=1
Sam=18
here=9
A=4
be=4
Could=3
In=2
I=84
box=7
Say=3
hero=1
Would=9
house=8
our=1
fox=7
point=1
not=65
see=4
car=7
are=2
and=15
bite=1
of=1
dark=7
eat=23
takes=1
so=3
on=7
That=2
a=56
green=12
or=8
may=4
will=21
could=11
ANYWHERE=2
say=2
boat=3
They=1
the=13
with=19
Ham=1
By=1
there=9
Let=1
tormented=1
So=2
Green=1
You=8
story=1
```

Comment: Try to make a smaller example using a smaller input and output. It's a bit hard to read your question with so much text. It will also make it easier to debug. Finally, is generateStatsFile() relevant to your question? It is currently not implemented.

Comment: Funny.In the correct output, the words are sorted by descending frequency and then *backward* alphabetical order.

Comment: You may either handcode your XML output or use some library for generating it.

Comment: “you should research better options”. Have you tried that? What came out of it?

Comment: I think that what you’re missing for ignoring case is [`String.toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase--).

Comment: I am currently researching options on it, its still in the works for that I was just trying to get the words to work with me by getting all toLowerCase, but it seems I may need to create a xml to do that for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this is what you are looking for. You want to convert to lower case every word when you take it from the `Scanner`. You can do this with something like this:

```
    String word = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
    if (map.containsKey(word)) {
        map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1);
    } else {
        map.put(word, 1);
    }
```

If you would like to have both a case sensitive and case insensitive map, you can do this with parallel maps.

Then when it comes to sorting by number of occurrences you can do something with a list of the keys that are sorted by their corresponding number of occurrences in the map:

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    // Populate map and do stuff

    List<String> sortedByOccurences = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());

    Collections.sort(sortedByOccurences, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return map.get(o1) - map.get(o2);
        }

    });
```

Hope this is close to what you are looking for.